# Writing testcase to confirm counter signal values in CAPL

Tags: capl

I am writing a basic CAPL test to check if a message counter is counting correctly with each cycle. I am trying the test case in simulated bus now, however whenever I check for the counter signal value using write() function I always get '0'and the signal value check always fails inside the loop. Why can't I see the signal updating in my testmodule at all although in the trace and the graphics it's updating correctly?
Here's the test module code below:

```
variables
{
  float counter1AB;
  int values [257];
  int count;
  long result;
  long cntResult;
}

void MainTest()
{
  //ChkConfig_Init("user");
  
  TestModuleTitle ("Cyclic time & Process counter check");
  TestModuleDescription ("Check the value of messages process counter is changing correctly.");
  TestModuleDescription ("Message ID Tested: 0x1AB");
  TestModuleDescription ("separate test cases.");  
  TestGroupBegin("message 0x1AB", "Check the process counter values for message 0x1AB");
  TC_MSg_1AB_first_value();
  
  write("signal value is %d", $Sig_cnt);
  testGroupEnd();
  
}

testcase TC_MSg_1AB_first_value()
{
  counter1AB=0;
  //check message 1AB recieved
  result = TestWaitForMessage(Av_VdsToSte1Scnd, 10000);
  cntResult = checkSignalMatch(Sig_cnt,counter1AB);
  if (result > 0){
    testStepPass("1.1","Message 0x1AB recieved for first time");
  }
  else{
    testStepFail("1.1","Message 0x1AB wasn't recieved for first time"); 
  }
  if (cntResult > 0){
    testStepPass("1.2","Message 0x1AB recieved with counter = %d ",counter1AB);
  }
  else{
    testStepFail("1.2","Message 0x1AB recieved with incorrect counter"); 
  } 
  //check that we have 255 subsequent transmissions afterwards
  for (count=0; count < 255; count++){
    result = TestWaitForMessage(0x1AB, 53);
    cntResult = checkSignalMatch(Sig_cnt,count+1);
    if (result > 0){
    testStepPass("1. %d","Message 0x1AB received for the %d th time",count+3,count+2);
    }
    else{
    testStepFail("1.%d","Message 0x1AB wasn't received for the %d th time",count+3,count+2); 
    }
    
    if (cntResult > 0){
      testStepPass("1.%d","Message 0x1AB received with counter = %d ", /*count+4,*/ count+1);
//      write("signal value is %d", $Sig_cnt);
    }
    else{
    testStepFail("1.%d","Message 0x1AB received with incorrect counter", count+4);
    //write("ExpectedValue= %d",count +1);
    
    }
  }
  write("signal value is %d", $Sig_cnt);
```

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your trace window, where the message and signals of interest can be seen?

Comment: Does the test module fail because of the variable `result` or `cntResult`?